# Something's changed in my profile picures setting, and it seems as it can be seen by public - can't change it!

Tags: facebook, privacy, photos

I have always had my pictures set to high privacy settings, but now I noticed that if I view it as "public" I can see my profile picture album. When I go to the album itself, is says "you can change the audience for each photo in this album" . When I go to each individual photo, the privacy settings are still high (i.e. friends, or now even just close friends) and it doesn't seem to change the fact that if I view it as "public" I can still see them! This was never the case before, as the only thing that could be seen was my profile picture (one) and the cover photos.

I wonder if somethig has changed and if anyone could please give me some advice, would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you browsing your profile as you or anonymously?

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you make an image your profile picture, it doesn't matter if its friends only or private, when its made into your profile picture, the profile picture automatically gets made public.

So if you don't want people see the full size version of your profile pic, after you setup your profile pic, you should change the privacy of the pic back to friends only, or whatever settings you like. You cannot change the privacy setting of the thumbnail profile picture however, as you used to be able to do a few years ago.